# Passing array of object into functional component and mapping

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use Material UI to create a reusable navigation tab, however, I am having trouble passing the object over to my functional component and mapping it out. Nothing displays when mapping.

I am fairly new to react hooks. Thanks in advance.

Class Component (passing state over to Navigation)

```
class MyWorkspace extends Component {
  state = {
    menuItem: [
      {
        name: "menu 01",
        urlPath: "/home/menu01"
      },
      {
        name: "menu 02",
        urlPath: "/home/menu02"
      },
      {
        name: "Reports",
        urlPath: "/home/menu03"
      },
    ],
   }
  }

render () {
 return (
  <div>
   <Navigation menuItem />
  </div>
 )
}
```

Functional Component

```
export default function Navigation({ menuItem }) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const MenuList = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {menuItem.map(item => {
          return <Tab label={item.name} className="Nav-Tab" />;
        })}
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="Nav-Title row">
        <Tabs
          className="Nav-Tab-List"
          value={value}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuList />
        </Tabs>       
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class component, you should assign a value to the prop being passed:

```
render () {
 return (
  <div>
   <Navigation menuItem={this.state.menuItem} />
  </div>
 )
}
```

In function component, you should call `MenuList()` inside the render :

```
export default function Navigation({ menuItem }) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const MenuList = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {menuItem.map(item => {
          return <Tab label={item.name} className="Nav-Tab" />;
        })}
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="Nav-Title row">
        <Tabs
          className="Nav-Tab-List"
          value={value}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {MenuList()} // call this or put the map here
        </Tabs>       
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define state in constructor

Second destruct menuitem from state

```
const {menuItem} = this.state
```

Third pass props like this

```
<Navigation menuItem={menuItem} />
```

If you pass like this  **Navigation menuItem />** you will get boolean value true inside child component.

Answer (score 0):

In MyWorkspace/render function, you don't actually pass the menuItem state.

`<Navigation menuItem />` will pass `menuItem` as `true` value. Replace it with: `<Navigation menuItem={this.state.menuItem} />`

Navigation component code looks correct